# Azure ADB2C Rest API additional InputClaims on Sign-In

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have set up a [REST API claims exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-exchange) to custom policies. This works fine when a new user signs-up.

My problem is that on user sign-in, I only receive the `objectId` as an input claim. I would like my REST API to receive some custom attributes stored in the user profile. For example, I would like my REST API to receive the `extension_termsOfUseConsentVersion` which I've set up following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-access).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The solution depends on whether this REST API call during sign in could return an error which you want to show to the screen, or to capture an error and do something with it in policy, eg show the TOS page again if the version is out of date. What do you want to do?

Comment: In general, you need to read the claim using an Azure AD Technical Profile, and then when calling the REST API, set it as an inputClaim so its send to the API.

Comment: I've managed to implement a working solution by following this page: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/working-with-custom-attributes-in-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies-fae1454b12bf

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following Item in the Metadata for your REST Technical Profile.

`<Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">nameOfRequestBodyClaim</Item>`

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#send-a-json-payload